# How to detect a SQL insertion in SQLAlchemy

Tags: events, insert, sqlalchemy

Hi I use SQLAlchemy for a web application. I want listen an event 'after_insert'.

```
class MyApp(Base):
    ...

def listen_after_insert(*args):
    ...

event.listen(MyApp, 'after_insert', listen_after_insert)
```

If i add a new app in my session, it 's work

```
session.add(MyApp(...))
session.commit()
```

But if the insert come from another application (ex: psql for postgres driver) it isn't work.

Who know how can I get the event if the insert come from another application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, the events are internal to the application.  If you want to detect external changes, you could write a trigger function, perhaps even in PL/Python, to somehow notify your application when certain events happen at the database level.